# how to dispatch all action like promise.all in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

```
async verify(){
    this.$store.dispatch('set', {
        key: this.value
    }).then(() => {
        this.$store.dispatch('verifyToken', {
            id: this.$store.state.token
        })
    .then(() => {
        this.$router.push('/')
    })
    }).catch(() => {
        this.$router.push('/login')
    })
}
```

if any of dispatch get failed it should redirect to login page otherwise keep working as sequencer like first dispatch set then verifyToken if all success then redirect to welcome page.

Please guide

Thanks

Comment: The promises aren't chained properly (not returned)

Answer (score 1):

You could use try/catch block:

```
async verify() {
    try {
        await this.$store.dispatch('set', {
            key: this.value
        });
        
        await this.$store.dispatch('verifyToken', {
            id: this.$store.state.token
        });

        this.$router.push('/');
    } catch (error) {
        this.$router.push('/login');
    }
}
```